# Command returns 0.0.0.0 for IP but only for leader

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have a 3 node docker swarm cluster and I am trying to get the IPs of each one via `docker node inspect node-1 --format '{{ .Status.Addr  }}'` but I am having an issue where when the node I am trying for (example `node-1` from above), that I get back `0.0.0.0`. This only happens on the leader node, the others work just fine.

What is happening in this case? Also, how can I use docker commands to get the IP of all the nodes when checking with their hostnames or `docker node ls`?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using {{.ManagerStatus.Addr}} and stripping the port number from the results with sed.

```
for NODE in $(docker  node ls -f 'role=manager' --format '{{.Hostname}}'); do
  docker node inspect --format '{{.ManagerStatus.Addr}}' ${NODE} | sed 's/:2377//'
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Related bug that i have found

> Status.Addr uses the gRPC library to determine the address of a given
> node as viewed by the manager. This means, for example, if a worker
> node was behind a proxy, it would give the proxy's address as
> Status.Addr, even if the worker itself didn't "know" it was behind a
> proxy.
>
> For ManagerStatus.Addr, the address given is the advertise address of
> the manager, as may have been set with --advertise-addr when doing
> init or join. The advertise address must be correct, because that's
> the address that the other managers know to connect to this manager
> at.

https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/35437